# How to organize jQuery in my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So I am getting to the point where I need to utilize the revealing module pattern or the object literal pattern, or are they the same pattern? I don't know. I understand the revealing module pattern uses closures but my knowledge is not deep yet. The revealing module pattern I have studied in the past and am a bit familiar with it.

The current situation I have is that I am using the jqGrid and I want to  consolidate common settings and event functions into one core.js or global.js file and then reuse all those settings and callback functions (like onSortCol func) every time I create a new jqGrid. I would like to be able to add or edit default settings/options of the jqGrid and this eludes me how I would set this up using the object literal pattern or the revealing module pattern with my default settings in a global.js file.

I was looking over this article:

http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/

And quickly I would like to know better what this code is doing:

```
var myFeature = {
    config : {
        wrapper : '#myFeature',
        container : 'div',
        urlBase : 'foo.php?item='
    },

    init : function(config) {
        $.extend(myFeature.config, config);
        $(myFeature.config.wrapper).find('li').
            each(function() {
                myFeature.getContent($(this));
            }).
            click(function() {
                myFeature.showContent($(this));
            });
    },

    buildUrl : function($li) {
        return myFeature.config.urlBase + $li.attr('id');
    },

    getContent : function($li) {
        $li.append(myFeature.config.container);
        var url = myFeature.buildUrl($li);
        $li.find(myFeature.config.container).load(url);
    },

    showContent : function($li) {
        $li.find('div').show();
        myFeature.hideContent($li.siblings());
    },

    hideContent : function($elements) {
        $elements.find('div').hide();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() { myFeature.init(); });
```

Let's just start with the init function. First, is the config "member" an object in the myFeature object, is that correct wording? Secondly, is the init "member" also an object in the myFeature object literal or since it is a function is it conceptualized differently then the config "member" of myFeature? Thirdly, what is the scope of config that is can be passed to the init function like it is in the myFeature object? Looking this code over I would expect to have to do this in my doc.ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var myF = new myF(); //new keyword not needed but can declared to emulate familiar
    object oriented programming concepts is what I think
    myF.init(myF.config); //I know I don't have to do this and this doesn't even make exact
    sense but just trying to express how my brain is working on this right now
 });
```

I will start there and see what kind of answers I get and adjust my question accordingly.

**UPDATE**
So config and init are properties of myFeature and init() can be passed an optional config object that will overwrite and append the passed config to the target myFeature.Config.

Next question, in the init implementation there is $.extend(myFeature.config, config). Why isn't the line $.extend(this.config,config)? This is where I think I want use the revealing module pattern because I can define a var called "self" and refer to **this** throughout the containing members of myFeature. I don't understand how in the object literal pattern the init property has access to myFeature within the function. It seems myFeature is globally scoped and all its properties and itself can be accessed by anyone at anytime, I know this is the nature of javascript but...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Would it really be better if I created a single question on SO for each question I have here? The overall question is a topic about patterns in javascript/jQuery so I see it building itself into a succinct question with answers many developers wanting to quickly understand a popular javascript pattern can refer to in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, those "members" are properties.

> "An object is a collection of properties and has a single prototype object. The prototype may be the null value." <sup>**[ECMA 4.3.3 object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.3)**</sup>

Next, `init` is just a function, assigned to the `myFeature` object property `init`. Functions are at their core also objects [brief demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rbtdf/).

> A function is a "member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in Function constructor and that may be invoked as a subroutine. In addition to its named properties, a function contains executable code and state that determine how it behaves when invoked."

Third, the scope of `config` being passed in is if you wish to include any additional properties. jQuery's extend (`$.extend(obj1,obj2)`) takes the properties from obj2 (an object) and then places them on obj1 (also an object, and in the case always `myFeature.config` which is pre-configured) [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LeWwt/).

Comment: I see so config is an optional argument that can be passed to init! Makes perfect sense!

Comment: I added an update to my question based on your helpful answer if you wouldn't mind checking out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> Next question, in the init implementation there is $.extend(myFeature.config, config). Why isn't the line $.extend(this.config,config)? This is where I think I want use the revealing module pattern because I can define a var called "self" and refer to this throughout the containing members of myFeature. I don't understand how in the object literal pattern the init property has access to myFeature within the function. It seems myFeature is globally scoped and all its properties and itself can be accessed by anyone at anytime, I know this is the nature of javascript but...

JavaScript does variable hoisting, which means that the interpreter will do 2 passes over your script block. The first pass will hoist any function and variable declarations to the top of the script block. The second pass will execute any initialization that was declared in the script block. The following self executing script block is an easy demonstration of how hoisting works.

```
// Original function block
var foo = 'string1';
(function() {
    alert(foo); // alerts undefined
    var foo = 'string2';
})();


// First pass, hoisting variables
var foo = 'string1';
(function() {
    // The var `foo` is hoisted to
    // the top of the script block
    var foo;
    alert(foo);
    foo = 'string2';
})();
```

Once the hoisting is complete the code will be executed. The local var `foo` has been hoisted and declared above the `alert` function, so when `alert` tries to access `foo` it is `undefined` because it was declared but not initialized. The var `myFeature` get's hoisted, whether it's global or contained within it's own closure. This makes it available along with the other properties contained in the object literal.

Also to note that with the object literal pattern instantiation is not required using the `new` operator. You also don't get private methods or properties. With `$.extend(myFeature.config, config);` `myFeature` can exist and `myFeature.config` might not. It's also easy to add or override current properties or methods to the object literal `myFeature` at runtime. You can read more about different JS patterns here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/